# How do I increase the magic mouse tracking speed

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, mouse, magic-mouse

I have gone to system preferences and set it to the absolutely maximum on the slider bar and its still fairly slow - much slower than I am used to on my PC!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Magic Prefs](http://magicprefs.com/)

[image]

Again, not native OSX, but lots of useful enhancements. I've been using it for months without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Get [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) (which you'll probably find a ton of other uses for). It lets you set much higher mouse speeds.

Comment: I was hoping it would just be a setting in OS-X?  Surely Apple has figured out people are having issues?

Comment: Sorry, nope. But BTT give the mouse the functionality it should have had from the beginning (more gestures than you can shake a stick at...)